# PHP stream multiple videos at once

Tags: php

I want to build a little streaming service, nothing like YouTube (there will be no options for users to upload videos themselves), I calculate with not much more than 100-200 concurrent streams at once. The videos are quite short, around 3-10 minutes in HD-quality and shouldn't be much bigger than 200mb. My question is, if this is possible with PHP and what kind of hardware would be needed, I thought maybe the hard drive read'n'write-rate could be too slow to stream 200 different videos at once...Any suggestions?

Comment: Not really a stack overflow question. But, in the worst case, assume a BluRay disc, 25GB, 2 hours of video, which means a total of 711 MB/s for 200 different streams. (I would worry more about storage capacity). Assuming a 4.7 (5)GB DVD, 2hours, you would get around 142MB/s for 200 streams. In other words, it depends greatly on the bitrate of your videos

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, i updatet my questions, forgot the sie of the video. we are talking about hd-videos which are quite short, let's say around 3-10 minutes with a size smaller than 200mb i think

Comment: Might be worth looking into third-party video streaming services - they have video-optimised servers and CDNs that (presumably) permit them to offer this service cheaper than one can do it oneself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think PHP would be not the best choice for network video streaming.

If you need just a video-streaming service without any custom extra-features, why don't you just use any existing solutions? For example, you could use [erlyvideo](http://erlyvideo.org/) - it is written on Erlang but it is easy to install & maintain and it is very optimized on hardware (so, you don't need monster-like video server).

I believe, 2-4 Gb RAM would be enough. And if you need streaming only (without encoding), you also don't need a very powerful CPU too.